# Inexplicable g++ error - "iostream: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, g++, iostream

About a month ago I was compiling fine with CodeBlocks on Windows 8. Today I tried to compile some code and I got the fatal error "iostream: No such file or directory". I tried using both CodeBlock's MinGW installation (which I managed to use the last time and haven't tampered with since) and a newer, independent MinGW installation. I got the same error with both. I tried compiling from the command line using the "g++" command, same error.

Here's an example file that gives me the error when I try to compile it.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Why me" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What's gone wrong?

Comment: Are you `using namespace std`? If not, `std::cout << "Why me" << std::endl`.

Comment: Good catch. I still get the same error, though.

Comment: The real issue is that I can't compile code that worked fine a month ago and that someone else has been able to compile without issue.

Comment: Undeliberately deinstalled the tool chain meanwhile??

Comment: Go to the global compiler settings, go to Toolchain settings and check the include directory. Does it have something like `"../MinGW/include"`?

Comment: The CodeBlocks compile path is this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW" But that shouldn't matter, I get the same error when compiling from the command line.

Comment: The obvious question. Is there a file called iostream in the lib?

Comment: Yep. In both the CodeBlocks and independent MinGW installations - `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\iostream` and `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream`, respectively.

Comment: "a newer, independent MinGW installation" ... did installing that one destroy the old one?

Comment: @Pineapple Your new MinGW tries to find files in PATH. It tries to find `C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.` **8** `.1\*`.

Comment: Sebastian: I don't think so. I thought it was possible the environment variables I set up when installing could have screwed something up, but I removed them and issue persisted. The CodeBlocks MinGW installation appears to be intact, and the newer installation seemed to be working when I used it for something else.

Comment: I don't understand - is there something I should or shouldn't do with the PATH variable to solve the issue?